# How to solve "HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW" with babel-node

Tags: node.js, request

I have to call a API to get some data. There is my code.

```
getRestaurant = async (id) => {
    return await request({
        uri: `https://domain/v3/information/${id}`,
        json: true,
    })
}
```

But there is a error show below.

```
{ RequestError: Error: Parse Error
    at new RequestError (/Users/eztable/Desktop/serverlesskit/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/Users/eztable/Desktop/serverlesskit/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/Users/eztable/Desktop/serverlesskit/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/Users/eztable/Desktop/serverlesskit/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (/Users/eztable/Desktop/serverlesskit/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:448:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: Parse Error',
  cause:
   { Error: Parse Error
       at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) bytesParsed: 8192, code: 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW' },
  error:
   { Error: Parse Error
       at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
       at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
       at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17) bytesParsed: 8192, code: 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW' }
```

I have searched for some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328725/hpe-header-overflow-exception-when-make-http-request) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) and try to add a flag `--max-http-header-size`. Actually, I don't know how to compile my node.js. And the second problem is that my node app is transformed by babel.

I can not make a command like `npx babel-node app.js --max-http-header-size=16384`

Is any method to let me using babel-node with the `--max-http-header-size` flag?

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issued and figured with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)
This can be done in

> package.json > scripts > start

e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js --max-http-header-size=80000"
}
```